# Unable to animate android view's height bigger than screen

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to animate the height and width of a view. The target height and width of the view are bigger than the screen but the view wont animate bigger than the screensize. The view grows until it reaches the screen height and then it stops.

This is my code:

```
private void openMenu6() {
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, AppData.height * 10);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            circle2.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            circle2.getLayoutParams().width = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            circle2.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    anim.start();
    openMenu = !openMenu;
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="classes.Blog">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/main_list" />

    <include layout="@layout/fullscreensliderpage" />

    <include layout="@layout/readlaterpage" />

    <include layout="@layout/searchpage" />

    <include layout="@layout/webviewpage" />

    <include layout="@layout/twitterpage" />

    <include layout="@layout/settingspage" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <classes.Circle
            android:id="@+id/circle2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <classes.Circle
            android:id="@+id/menuCircle"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button" />

    </RelativeLayout> ...
```

Comment: Try to animate full screen and than use scale.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me a lot. I now scale the view up to 4f at startup this didnt changed much becaus it had a widht and hight of 0 (0*4 = 0), but when i scale it up it works like a charm!